# Подключение к веб-камере Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Пытаюсь подключиться к веб-камере клиента через Python.

```
#form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# text1 = form.getfirst("TEXT_1", "не задано")
# text2 = form.getfirst("TEXT_2", "не задано")

print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("""<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Обработка данных форм</title>
    </head>
    <body>""")
print("<h1>12312!</h1>")

import cv2
import os

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640)  # set video width
cam.set(4, 480)  # set video height

face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml')

# For each person, enter one numeric face id
face_id = 1

print("\n [INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...")
# Initialize individual sampling face count
count = 0

while (True):

    ret, img = cam.read()
    # img = cv2.flip(img, -1)  # flip video image vertically
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    count += 1

    # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
    cv2.imwrite("dataset/User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff  # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
if k == 27:
    break
elif count >= 30:  # Take 30 face sample and stop video
    break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("""</body>
    </html>""")
```

Но выдаётся следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кст, странный метод запуска скрипта :) Вы хотите стримить с камеры на вебсайт?

Comment: @gil9red пытаюсь получить 30 фотографий с веб-камеры клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Есть некоторые замечания:

1. Добавьте проверку успешности подключения к камере

   Пример:

   ```
   number_camera = 0
   cam = cv2.VideoCapture(number_camera)
   if not cap.isOpened():
       print(f'[-] Unsuccessful capture of camera number {number_camera!r}.')
       return
   ```
2. Проверяйте значение `ret` из `cap.read()`:

   ```
   while True:
       ret, img = cap.read()
       if not ret:
           continue
   ```

Comment: Проверка пройдена безуспешно.

Comment: @Данила, у меня этот код с usb камерами работал. Проверьте что они доступны на машине, где скрипт запускается. Возможно камера недоступна по индексу 0, проверьте следующие индексы 1, 2 и т.д. (но маловероятно, что в этом проблема). Кст, если нужно потестить код без камеры, то `cv2.VideoCapture` принимает еще строку -- так можно путь к файлу с видео на машине указать

Comment: @Данила, если мой ответ помог с определением ошибки, [то проголосуйте за него и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)